# apply transforms integers to strings

Tags: r

When I do

```
a = c('a', 'b', 'c')
b = c(1, 2, 3)
t = data.frame(a, b)
apply(t, 1, print)
```

, apply transforms my numeric columns to strings.

However, when I do

```
a = c(2, 3, 4)
b = c(1, 2, 3)
t = data.frame(a, b)
apply(t, 1, print)
```

, apply does not transform my numeric columns to strings.

However, I would need apply to always leave the columns as they are and not transform their class automatically. How can I prevent apply from automatically transforming my input classes?

EDIT:
I am specifically interested in **looping through rows**.

Comment: `apply` is the wrong tool here. If you read the docs you'll see that the first thing it does is coerce it's argument to a matrix, which forces all data to be the same type. If you're working on columns, consider `lapply`.

Comment: @divibisan Good job finding that duplicate, I was struggling to find a decent one.

Comment: @joran The solution you marked works well for looping through columns. Do you have a solution for looping through rows?

Comment: So, if you think about that for a second, you'll realize that from R's data structure perspectives, what you're looking for is sort of nonsensical, rowwise. A data frame is designed to hold columns of potentially different types. If you look at a row in isolation and want to treat it as a "vector" R *has* to coerce it, since atomic vectors must be of a single type. If you have complex rowwise operations, you are often left just writing a for loop.

Comment: ...since the only way to operate on a row at a time without changing types is to either leave it as a 1 row data frame, or remove the data.frame piece and treat it as a plain list.

Answer (score 0):

The function `apply` transforms the data frame into a matrix before applying the function. Since matrices can store values of one type only, all values in the data frame are cast into the most general data type. The character data type is more general than numeric values.